# Activate JS function on click of DIV or A tag

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to pass some data via ajax to a php file but only if an element is clicked.

How can I attach each A element to the corresponding JS function, and only once clicked?

```
<a class="rating star1">1</a><br />
<a class="rating star2">2</a><br />
<a class="rating star3">3</a><br />

<script>
//CANT WORK OUT HOW TO ACTIVATE THIS FUNCTION ONLY IF .star1 IS CLICKED
function() { 
    $.post('/rate.php', {
    rating : '1', 
    page_id : '1234'
}, function(){
    });
}

//CANT WORK OUT HOW TO ACTIVATE THIS FUNCTION ONLY IF .star2 IS CLICKED
function() { 
    $.post('/rate.php', {
    rating : '2', 
    page_id : '1234'
}, function(){
    });
}

//CANT WORK OUT HOW TO ACTIVATE THIS FUNCTION ONLY IF .star3 IS CLICKED
function() { 
    $.post('/rate.php', {
    rating : '3', 
    page_id : '1234'
}, function(){
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a click event handler to all elements with the class `rating`.  If you bind the click event handler to `rating` you can eliminate some duplicate code.

```
$(".rating").click(function(){
    $.post("/rate.php", {
        rating: $(this).html(), //will grab the rating from the html of clicked <a/>
        page_id: "1234"
    },function(){});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to provide a function for each link

HTML

```
<a class="rating" data-rate="1" >1</a><br />
<a class="rating" data-rate="2">2</a><br />
<a class="rating" data-rate="3">3</a><br />
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rating').click(function(){
        var rating_val = $(this).data('rate').val();
        $.post('/rate.php', {
            rating : rating_val, 
            page_id : '1234'
            }, function(){
        });        
    }
});
```

Comment: hi, thanks for this. It doesn't appear to be sending the data over to the PHP file. I have done exactly what you have posted but it isnt working. The PHP file updates the database, if I run the PHP file in the browser manually with manual numbers it works fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, i provided the val() function after grabbing the data-rate attribute from the clicked element.

this should be
    -- $(this).data('rate') --
instead of
    -- $(this).data('rate').val() --

Sorry again :)